# How to generalize from interval to reals

Tags: real-analysis

I can show, using Mean Value Theorem, that if $g: I \to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function from an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $g'(x) = 0$ for all $x\in I$ then $g$ is constant.

This is a theorem about functions on intervals. I believe it is also true that if $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is such that $g'(x) =0$ then also $g$ is constant.

How to deduce the theorem for $\mathbb R$ given the theorem for $I$?

Comment: If $g(a)\ne g(b)$ (with $a\lt b$), then $g$ isn't constant on the interval $[a-1,b+1]$.

Comment: Actually, most authors would consider $\mathbb R$ to be an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ and is constant on any interval then it is constant on $\mathbb R$. If $g(x)\ne g(y)$ then you can easily find an interval containing $x$ and $y$ and a contradiction is found.

Answer (score 2):

Use the mean value theorem to show that $g(x)=g(0)$ for all $x\ne 0$ by considering the interval between $0$ and $x$.